# Программная обработка звука

Tags: аудио, алгоритм, фильтры

Здравствуйте.

У меня есть звуковой файл, на котором запись человеческого голоса. Мне нужно программно улучшить качество звука (увеличить соотношение сигнал/шум, применить фильтрацию).

Искал информацию в интернете - много где написано что нужно использовать преобразования Фурье, но мне не понятно как его применять. Может быть у кого-нибудь есть ссылки на библиотеки, исходники или статьи, в которых поподробнее описан процесс преобразований. Или кто-то сам сталкивался с таким заданием.

Comment: Вы хотите именно написать код, который будет обрабатывать звуковой файл, или вам подсказать бесплатные программы, которые это умеют?

Comment: Скорее всего ему нужен какой то консольный скрипт, который будет использовать ПО для этого. Хотя как то не совсем ясно.

Comment: @sergiks, @dimka3210 
Либо самому написать код для обработки звукового файла либо воспользоваться готовой библиотекой, стороннее ПО использовать не надо.   
Если таких библиотек не найду - придется самому писать код.  А вот как написать код, который будет обрабатывать звуковой файл - не знаю.

Comment: Читайте про цифровую обработку сигналов, всё поймёте. Там и про Фурье, и про фильтры, и много чего ещё.